# Prove a bisimulation relation

Tags: automata, proof-techniques, correctness-proof

I need to prove a bisimulation relation on $CA_{\tau}(N)$ (communication algebra with tau-steps) and names $N$.

It need to prove that $p!d.x||p?d.y$ is bisimular with $p!d.(x||p?d.y)+p?d.(p!d.x||y)$ by finding a suitable bisimulation relation $R$.

I was thinking of $R=\{(x,x) \mid x \text{ is a reachable state} \} \cup \{(p!d.(x||p?d.y)+p?d.(p!d.x||y) \mid x\text{ and }y \text{ are reachable states} \}$.

Is this a suitable relation? How do I prove that.

Note: the definition of bisimularity in this book is:
$x$ is bisimilar with $y$ when there exists and relation $R$ on automata $M$ and $M'$ with sets of states $S$, $S'$ such that:

1. $R$ relates the reachable states
2. $R$ relates the initial states
3. Whenever $sRs'$ and $s$ has an $a$ step to $t$ for some $a$ in the alphabet, then there are states $s''$ and $t'$ in $S'$ such that $s'$ has an $\epsilon$ path to $s''$ and $s''$ has an $a$ step to $t'$ and both $sRs''$ and $tRt'$.
4. Whenever $sRs'$ and $s'$ has an $a$ step to $t'$, then there are states $s''$ and $t$ in $S$ such that $s$ has an $\epsilon$ path to $s''$ and $s''$ has an $a$ step to $t$ and both $s''Rs'$ and $tRt'$.
5. Whenever $sRs'$ and $s$ has an $\tau$ step to $t$, then there are states $s''$ and $t'$ in $S'$ such that $s'$ has an $\epsilon$ path to $s''$ and either:

   1. $s''=t'$ or
   2. $s''$ has an $\tau$ step to $t'$ and both $sRs'$ and $tRt'$
6. Same as $5$, but then from $M'$ to $M$.
7. Whenever $sRs'$ and $s'$ terminates, then there is a state $s''$ in $S'$ such that $s'$ has an $\epsilon$ path to $s''$ and $s''$ terminates and $sRs''$.
8. Same as 7, but then from $M'$ to $M$.

How can I prove such relation?

Comment: Your relation is not a set of pairs. When you will have a relation $R$ that is indeed a set of pairs, you will need to check that $R$ verifies all clauses of the definition. If it does not, modify $R$ until it does.

Comment: In general, you will have problems with the "all reachable states" part of your relation: how can you actually compute something with that? In your example, you can simply compute all reachable states.